# What are the estimates in total neurons and average connections per neuron for each of the processing areas of the visual cortex?

Tags: neuroscience, vision

I am trying to find ballpark estimates for the number of neurons in each functional area of the visual cortex (V1, V2, V3, etc). While nice if known, the numbers themselves are not as important to me as the relative size differences of the areas, so this information would be just as welcomed.

Also, if known, are the total synapse averages fairly consistent between areas, or do they change dramatically?

I have found rough estimates for V1 here: http://www.vision.caltech.edu/~harel/fun/v1.html but am having trouble finding this sort of information out for subsequent areas.

Answer (score 2):

I found a table listing the relative volumes of 39 different BAs in the supplementary material of:
[Hazlett, Erin A. et al. "Cortical Gray and White Matter Volume in Unmedicated Schizotypal and Schizophrenia Patients"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2672563/), which seems to be open-access.

This data is from MRI scans of 148 healthy controls. The mean total brain volume was 1216cm.

Not sure how the density of neurons differs across areas.

[Here is a link to the supplementary pdf](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2672563/bin/NIHMS51479-supplement-01.pdf)